# Updating uploaded content on Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have a problem with updating our uploaded content on Amazon S3. We keep our software updates on Amazon S3. We overwrite the old version of our software on S3 with new versions. Sometimes our users get old versions of files, when new versions have already been uploaded over 10 hours ago.

Step by step actions of our team:

1. We upload our file (size about 300 mb) on S3
2. This file is located on S3 for some time; more than a day, usually some weeks.
3. We upload a new version of the file to S3, overwriting the old version of this file
4. We start testing downloads. Some people get new versions, but another people get old versions.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should use different file names for different versions, this would make sure that some crazy proxy won't cache old file.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you try to use [S3 Object Versioning](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectVersioning.html), and place CloudFront in the solution to expose a short TTL Expiry to make it clear to caches to dismiss it ASAP.

Just a note for CloudFront: Make sure to Invalidate the CloudFront Cache for the Object when releasing a new version